# Scala Play Framework Editing a value and storing the new value

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I have a need in my web application where I need to allow a user to **update an existing item**. However I want to know how I can store the original value so that it can be deleted and the new one used once the user has filled in the form.

**Let me expand a bit:**

Basically, I initially provide the user with a form to fill. After the form is filled in, I create an object from the properties of the form - things like age, name, height, etc are stored in an object, let's call it Person:

```
case class Person(age: Int, name: String, height: Int)
```

**Now this information can be edited when the user clicks an edit button** beside the item. So on the website, there is an option to edit the person.

My question is, ***how do I store the previous person, and once the user presses `Update` on the site, I am able to delete the original person object and replace it with the new one?***

My current solution is to store the original object in **the Session** (as JSON), then when the form is updated, I read the JSON from the session to do more work.

**I feel like this is not safe** because (correct me if I'm wrong) it is possible to change the session data json from outside the app, thus allowing someone to change the person's name or something and I will not know this and then delete the wrong person from the list rather than the one I was going to update.

```
def editPerson(name: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    Person.findByName(name).map { person =>
        val form = personForm.fill(person)
        Ok(views.html.persons.editPerson(form))
          .addingToSession(("Edit", Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(person))))
    } getOrElse NotFound
}
```

The above method is mapped to a route which allows one to specify a person to edit. When the `Update` button is pressed, the following controller method is called:

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
    val newPersonForm = personForm.bindFromRequest()

    newPersonForm.fold(
        hasErrors = { form =>
            request.session.get("Edit").map { person =>
                Redirect(routes.Persons.editPerson(person.name))
                  .flashing(Flash(form.data) + ("error" -> Messages("validation.errors")))
            } getOrElse(BadRequest.removingFromSession("Edit"))
        },

        success = { newPerson =>
            request.session.get("Edit").foreach { prevP =>
                Person.remove(prevP) // delete the person that was edited
            }
            Person.add(newPerson) // add the new person
            val message = Messages("persons.new.success", newPerson.name)
            Redirect(routes.Persons.show(newPerson.name)).flashing("success" -> message).removingFromSession("Edit")
        }
    )
}
```

What the above `save` method does is that if the form was completed with errors, the person information is read once again from the session and we are redirected to the edit page once more.
If the form has no errors, we once again read the person information from the session and this time, it is deleted and the new person added.

**What other methods can I use to ensure that the object is not exposed to the outside and remains within the controller until the user enters valid values in the form, at which point the object to edit is then deleted and the new one added?**